# what external content is accessed when visiting a page

Tags: firefox-addon, loading, external, html, statusbar

When we open a new webpage, usually some external content is loaded. Like Google Analysis, ads from third parties, as we see though the status bar (i.e. Reading google-analysis.com...).

I wonder if there is an add-on for Firefox that remembers what content is loaded for a certain webpage, or a log of what appeared in the status bar.

An example would be (Firefox statue bar history):

Status bar history for page1.com:
1.loading page1.com
2.loading google-analysis.com
3.loading some-ad-provider.com
4.done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press Ctrl+Shift+K and then reload the page, all the requests the page makes will be visible.